# Dual of finite-dimensional subspace of the dual vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $V$ be a (possibly infinite-dimensional) vector space. Let $U \subseteq V^*$ be a finite-dimensional vector subspace. Define $W = \{v \in V: f(v)=0 \text{ for all } f \in U \}$. Does it then follow that $V/W \cong U^*$?

Here is my attempt at a proof:
Consider the map $\psi: V/W \to U^*$ given by $v+W \mapsto (f \mapsto f(v))$. This is a well-defined linear map and is injective just by the definition of $W$. We now want to show that it is surjective. Let $e: V \to V^{**}$ be the natural map. I claim that $U^* \subseteq e(V)$. If this were true I claim that $q \circ e^{-1}: U^* \to V/W$ is inverse to $\psi$.

I am now sure how to prove the key claim that $U^* \subseteq e(V)$ (nor even if it is true). Perhaps there is a better way to prove this proposition?

Comment: Your definition of $W$ doesn't make sense. Perhaps you means $f(a)=0$ for all $f\in U$, or something similar?

Comment: @Mark yes that's exactly what I mean, thank you

Comment: If $V$ is finite-dimensional, no problem ($e$ is onto). Else, it is not true (e.g. $U=V^*$).

Comment: @AnneBauval I have specified that $U$ is finite-dimensional, so taking $U+V^*$ does not give a counterexample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim $U^*\subset e(V)$ may be proved as follows.

Let $(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ be a basis of $U.$

Since $f_1$ is not a linear combination of $f_2,\dots,f_n,$ its kernel does not contain the intersection of theirs, i.e.
$$\exists v_1\in V\quad f_1(v_1)=1\quad\text{and}\quad f_2(v_1)=\dots=f_n(v_1)=0.$$
Similarily, $\exists v_2,\dots,v_n\in V$
$$\forall i,j\quad f_i(v_j)=\delta_{i,j}.$$
Then,
$$\forall\varphi\in U^*\quad\varphi=e\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\varphi(f_i)v_i\right).$$